# Batch File: Function, create string of a specific character, x number of times

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Please help with my script is not working.

```
@echo off
echo Printing repeated character
call :printStrings retVal 3 #
echo Returned String: "%retVal%"
PAUSE
:printStrings
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set /a "Number=%~2"
    rem set /a "counter=60-!Number!"
    set "returnStr="
    set "repeatChar=%~3"
    rem echo Character to repeat: %repeatChar%
    FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,!Number!) DO (
        set "returnStr=%returnStr%%repeatChar%"             
        echo Adding character
    )   
)
( 
    endlocal    
    set "%~1=%returnStr%"
    rem set "%~1=%repeatChar%"
    exit /b
)
```

I need to print a specific character x number of times by calling the function, so if i do

```
call :printStrings retVal 3 #
```

Expected output will be

Returned String: "###"

Comment: _my script is not working_, Aha, you tested on an iPhone or you tried it on linux, or what part is not working?

Comment: The returned Value is always empty even though "Adding character" is printed 3 times.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#4DOS_Batch is interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the DelayedExpansion, but not at the important line.
`set "returnStr=%returnStr%%repeatChar%"`  will fail, as the expansion of %returnStr% and also of %repeatChar% is done *before* the line will be executed.

Change it to `set "returnStr=!returnStr!!repeatChar!"` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

**::why complicate something so simple**

```
::************************************

::********-Modify-*******
set "Col=10"
set "Char=#"
::********-Modify-*******

:loop
set /a loopEx+=1
set loop=%loop%%char%
IF "%loopEx%" == "%col%" goto :Exloop
goto :loop
:Exloop

::********-Modify-*******
Echo(%loop%>> File.txt
::********-Modify-*******

::****Code by S-S Guca Srbija 2019****
```

**OR**

```
::************************************

::********-Modify-*******
set "Col=10"
set "Char==&"
::********-Modify-*******

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:loop
set /a loopEx+=1
set loop=!loop!!char!
IF "!loopEx!" == "!col!" goto :Exloop
goto :loop
:Exloop
Set loop="!loop!"
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

::********-Modify-*******
Echo(%loop%>> File.txt
::********-Modify-*******

::****Code by S-S Guca Srbija 2019****
```

**OR**

```
@echo off
set "numbifor=15"
set "numafter=15"
set "mesag=i can do everything in MS-DOS"
set "MyChar=*"
::***********************************************
Call :PrintString %numbifor% %MyChar% RetVal1
Set "numbifor=%RetVal1%"
Call :PrintString %numafter% %MyChar% RetVal2
Set "numafter=%RetVal2%"
goto:EXnext
:PrintString
set "Col=%~1"
set "Char=%~2"
:loop
set /a "loopEx+=1"
set loop=%loop%%char%
IF "%loopEx%"=="%col%" goto:Exloop
goto:loop
:Exloop
Set "%~3=%loop%"
Set "loopEx="
Set "loop="
Goto:eof
:EXnext
::***********************************************
set "msg=::%numbifor%-%mesag%-%numafter%"
echo(%msg% | clip >nul
Exit
::*********-Code by S-S Guca Srbija 2019-********
```

**:: Modify the code as you needed**

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: The complete code it uses is quite complicated for such a simple function